# Calling an API with retrofit when widget button clicked

Tags: android, android-widget

I am writing an app widget where on a button when clicked, it should trigger an API call with retrofit that would send some data on my server. I have designed the layout. My widget is ready. But now I want to add apply action on the button. What is the best possible solution for this? Using a Job Schedular or a Service maybe? Or some other method?

Comment: Why do you want to use a service or Job scheduler for the above task? If your intention is to post the data to the server immediately when the button is clicked you can invoke your API call on button click directly. No need for service or Job scheduler

Comment: AppWidgetProvider gives us remoteviews. And to add that some onclick action to some view, it needs a pending intent. i.e. views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_update, pendingIntent); How can I directly invoke API call?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I didn't properly understand the question. To answer your question, I would use a JobIntentService to make my network call , so to accommodate the Oreo background restrictions

Comment: Hi. Have you solved your problem? And how?